# To use this setting, get a subscription to Enterprise Mobility + Security and assign a license to yourself. Manage subscriptions

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration

I want to set un-managed devices control policy.
Unfortunately, when i tried to do so, i got the below error:-

> To use this setting, get a subscription to Enterprise Mobility + Security and assign a license to yourself. Manage subscriptions

[image]

any advice?

Comment: Which Microsoft 365 plan you are using?

Comment: @GaneshSanap E1

Comment: To use this feature, I think you will need [Enterprise Mobility + Security E3 or E5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-365/enterprise-mobility-security/compare-plans-and-pricing) license. Check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-from-unmanaged-devices), maybe you can find something useful related to this feature.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the info.. but do i need this license for all users or only the office 365 admin?

Comment: @johnGu You will have to assign the above licenses to all the users that you wish to have the features from the licenses.

Comment: @jimas13 so if i define to block-access on unmanaged devices.. and a user with E1 license access the site from unmanaged device then his access will not be blocked? second question what about external users whose does not have any license inside our tenant, will they bypass this access policy?

Answer (score 0):

There is the same post on the [Q&A Forum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/), I suggest you can follow the progress of the post.

- **[To use this setting, get a subscription to Enterprise Mobility +
  Security and assign a license to yourself. Manage subscriptions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/454615/to-use-this-setting-get-a-subscription-to-enterpri.html)**